# How to update portions of output in C++?

Tags: c++, output

So I want to update some numbers in lines of code without reprinting them, for instance, some percentages. Fortunately, I've got a bit of help using `\r` carriage return, but the thing is that I want to use this on new lines and this ain't working with `\n` or `std::endl`

Example:

```
int gameTime = 0;
do 
{
    \\ I need a new line after the below one

    printf("%d'\r", gameTime);
    std::cout << "\nattempt";        
    Sleep(450);
    gameTime++;



} while (gameTime <= 90);
```

Comment: In linux you do this with a library like `ncurses` with that said I see you are using windows.

Comment: Console isn't too suitable for modifying reported text.

Answer (score 0):

Both windows and linux support these escape codes:

https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r92094/c++/VT100.html

Where that page says `^[`, you should insert `\033`.